# getting notified when addressbook updates

Tags: ios, tableview, addressbook

I am trying to get updates from `addressBook` using the predefined method

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, self);

void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    NSLog(@"AddressBook Changed");
    [self getContactsFromAddressBook];
}
```

I am calling `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, self);` in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, then i do the callback method, how can use self inside that c method? how can i update my tableview if i can't use my objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly use `self` in that function - but you're passing self as the context when you register for the change callback, so it will be passed as an argument in the addressBookChanged function.

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    NSLog(@"AddressBook Changed");
    YourClass *yourInstance = (__bridge YourClass *)(context)
    [yourInstance getContactsFromAddressBook];
}
```

to be more specific to your classes -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, self.wkListVC);     
    return YES; 
}

void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) 
{     
    NSLog(@"AddressBook Changed");     
    wbkABViewControllerTableViewController *myVC = (__bridge wbkABViewControllerTableViewController *)context;
    [myVC getPersonOutOfAddressBook]; 
}
```

Make sure self.wkListVC is not nil when you register for the change callback.

Comment: and i cast my context that i send in the callback function `((__bridge void*) myClass)`?
when i do that i find that my context in equal to nil, so i am not getting the object. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
     ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *)self.wkListVC);
    return YES;
}`

Comment: `void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    NSLog(@"AddressBook Changed");
    wbkABViewControllerTableViewController *myVC = (__bridge     wbkABViewControllerTableViewController *)context;
   [myVC getPersonOutOfAddressBook];
}
`

Comment: Ok, now we reach the point of my issue, i can't send `self.wkListVC` as a parameter, it still says - undeclared identifier "self" - , the solution Xcode debugger offer is to put (__bridge void*) in front of it, and when i do so, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You do need to cast `self.wkListVC` with (__bridge void *) - but if its nil in the addressBookChanged function, then it was either nil when you passed it in as an argument to ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback, or you've dereferenced it since registering for the call back.  Try using `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *)self);` and then `wbkAppDelegate *appDelegate = (__bridge wbkAppDelegate *)context` in the callback function.  You can then pull your view controller off of that.